# NFS performace degradation

Tags: nfs

I work for a small software house.

We share our developers' home directories over NFS.  The primary use for this is to host the users' git repository.

Since last week, there has been a signficant degradation in performance.  For example, cmake invocation (used by our build system) has slowed down markedly.  I don't have numbers for a build on nfs share from before the slowdown, but the comparison between local disk and nfs for this task is:

> Local: 29.3s 
>   NFS: 9m 46.9s (586s)

So we have this job running (rather neatly) 20x slower on the NFS share.  Load average on the NFS server is not high.  If anything, we have fewer staff working due to people taking annual leave in August.  I think it must be either network or server specific because the problem is seen from multiple clients.

What might cause this kind of slowdown?

Edit:
Server is Centos 6.3 running on a DL180G6. Kernel is 2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64. Clients are generally Centos 6.2 and 6.3. Network is 1G ethernet with utp cabling. Network mount points are shared via NIS maps. The server is running `autofs-5.0.5-54.el6.x86_64`.

The export line in /etc/exports on the NFS server is:

```
/export/home 10.0.1.0/24(rw,nohide,no_root_squash,sync) 10.1.0.0/24(rw,nohide,no_root_squash,sync)
```

The timestamp on this file does not suggest that this has been edited recently.

Comment: What are your NFS mount options?

Comment: When you typed out this question did no part of your conscious mind not consider adding some of the pertinent details here? say make/model of whatever your NFS servers is, OS version, config, filesystem, network design - you know, some form of actual detail that might give us a 1% chance of helping you here. This is the technical version of "My car had broken down, it's a blue one".

Comment: Harsh...but fair!

Server is Centos 6.3 running on a DL180G6.  Kernel is 2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64.
Clients are generally Centos 6.2 and 6.3.
Network is 1G ethernet with utp cabling.

Network mount points are shared via NIS maps.  The server is running autofs: autofs-5.0.5-54.el6.x86_64

I'll put the share options into a separate comment, because I'm running out of characters.

Comment: The export line in /etc/exports on the NFS server is:
/export/home    10.0.1.0/24(rw,nohide,no_root_squash,sync) 10.1.0.0/24(rw,nohide,no_root_squash,sync)
The timestamp on this file does not suggest that this has been edited recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer turned out to be an error on the RAID card.

Sorry for the inconvenience.  I write because of the slim possibilty that someone else might hit something similar.

To recap: 
build duration slowed down by a factor of ~3, and the duration was consistent +/-10%, hence suggesting that load wasn't the primary factor.